# User Seeds Laravel no funcionan correctamente con Passport

Tags: laravel, oauth, passport, seeders

estoy desarrollando una API en [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) apoyándome en la autenticación que proporciona [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport), poblando la base de datos de desarrollo con los [Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding) y realizando las pruebas con el cliente [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

El problema es el siguiente:

> Al poblar mi tabla **Users** con los *Seeders* e intentar hacer un *login* contra la ruta **`POST: /oauth/tokens`** qué *Passport* genera con alguno de los usuarios poblados no funciona, el mensaje que responde siempre es el mismo: credenciales inválidas. Pero, si registro un nuevo usuario con mi controlador que hace lo mismo qué el *seeder*, `User::create([...])` e intento luego *login* pues sí que funciona.

Necesito poder utilizar los usuarios poblados para login para no estar creando a mano los usuarios para que puedan utilizar el oauth.

La configuración de mi cliente de passport, es de tipo password, la demás configuración/instalación de passport está bien realizada ya qué funciona cuando creo un usuario a mano. La entidad User tiene el trait HasApiTokens.

#### ¿Dónde está el problema?

## Update

> **UserController**

```
<?php

...

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $this->validate($request, User::STORE_RULES);

            DB::beginTransaction();

            $input = $request->all();
            $user = User::create($input);

            DB::commit();

            return Response::json([
                'code' => 200,
                'message' => 'OK',
                'url' => url("/api/v1/users"),
                'data' => User::whereId($user->id)->first(),
            ]);
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            return Response::json([
                'code' => 400,
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'url' => url("/api/v1/users"),
                'data' => $e->validator->errors()->all(),
            ]);
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return Response::json([
                'code' => 500,
                'message' => 'KO',
                'url' => url("/api/v1/users"),
                'data' => [],
            ]);
        }
}

...
```

> **UserTableSeeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 1)->create()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->name = 'username';
            $user->phone = '666 666 666';
            $user->email = 'foo@admin.es';
            $user->password = bcrypt('root');
            $user->role_id = App\Role::whereName('admin')->first()->id;
            $user->save();
        });
        factory(App\User::class, 19)->create();
    }
}
```

> Proceso

```
composer install
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:client --password
php artisan passport:keys
php artisan config:cache
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos algo de código? Al menos los seeders, para intentar crear un escenario similar.

Comment: Viste si la base de datos es exactamente igual al crear con seeders y manual? Parte por eso. Quizá tu seeder no sigue el mismo proceso que el controlador.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta mostrando código.

Comment: Me parece extraño que te funcione el del `controlador` y no el del `seeder`, debería ser al revés, que el `controlador` no sirva pero el `seeder` SI. ¿estas seguro que el `controlador` sirva pero el `seeder` NO?

Comment: Estoy seguro @PabloContreras, el fillable es correcto también, es en algún proceso qué passport no genera lo debido, pero en los test funcionales si lo hace, es que eso es otra...

Comment: En el `seeder` intenta eliminando el `bcrypt()` que tiene la contraseña. Quedando la linea de la siguiente forma: `$user->password = 'root';`. Me avisas que tal te fue.

Comment: Eso era @PabloContreras, mil gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deduzco que el problema esta en que

> la autenticación que proporciona Passport

No desencripta o no valida el `bcrypt`.

¿Por que el `controller` sirve pero el `seeder` no?

En el `controller` lo estas registrando sin encriptacion y en el `seeder` lo haces con `bcrypt()`.
La solucion seria dejar el

> **UserTableSeeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 1)->create()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->name = 'username';
            $user->phone = '666 666 666';
            $user->email = 'foo@admin.es';
            $user->password = 'root';
            $user->role_id = App\Role::whereName('admin')->first()->id;
            $user->save();
        });
        factory(App\User::class, 19)->create();
    }
}
```

O sino te da solución, pues el siguiente paso es averiguar que comprobación de password tiene el **Passport**

Comment: Ahí estaba la solución, en mi entidad User tenía un setPasswordAttribute donde encriptaba la password, en el model factory de user tambien encriptaba, por lo tanto encriptaba 2 veces en los seeds, gracias!!!

Comment: Por eso es que la primera vez que vi la pregunta me parecía extraño, luego que ayer la vi en la en "destacadas" dije "¿Por que?" y mi única deducción era esa. De nada hermano, estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: Ademas te paso un enlace (https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) de toda la info para crear `Seeder` a tu gusto.